# A subgroup generated by arbitrarily infinite set of multiples of a element g is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a question from my midterm in group theory, which I had difficulty proving, here is the question:

Let G be a group, and S be an arbitrarily infinite set of integers, then let g be a specific element in G, prove that
$$H=\langle g^a|a \in S \rangle$$
is cyclic.

Here is my guess on the midterm:

Let $d=\min_{a\in S}|a|$, Yet I know this is not the right answer. My second guess(after midterm) is
$$d=\max\{m:\forall n\in S,m|n\}$$
Is this the correct answer, if it is I need some ideas to prove that $g^d \in H$.

Comment: since every element of $H$ is of the form $g^{k},k\in \mathbb{Z}$,u can modify your first choice by defining $d=\min\{\lvert k\rvert \backslash g^{k}\in H\}$.

Comment: Three-letter hint. G. C. D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $h\in H$, then $h$ is a "word" in powers of $g$.  Hence $h$ is a power of $g$.

Recall $\langle K\rangle $ is a subgroup of the group consisting in all words consisting in elements of $K$, since that's indeed a subgroup of $G$ containing $K$.

Let $d$ be the smallest positive power of $g$ in $H$.  Let $g^k\in H$.  Write $ k=dq+r$ with $0\le r\lt d$.  Then $g^r=g^ kg^{-dq}\in H\implies r=0$.  Thus $d\mid k $.  Thus $\langle g^d\rangle =H$.